# Subdomain throwing error 404 to few customers.

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, dns

I have my website http://www.mouryadandu.com which is hosted on photo shelter. I recently build a blog and wanted to host it on a separate hosting service. I already was having a multi site hosting service plan and decided to use add on domain to connect my blog. I have pointed the blog.mouryadandu.com subdomain to the server. The DNS propagation took few days but I was finally able to access the blog and successfully modify. Now when I share it, some people across the world are complaning they are seeing error 404 Page not Found. I also when share it on Facebook, its throwing error 404 instead of pulling the image. But for majority it seems not a problem , but I don't want this issue once the blog becomes permanent. I have a feeling there is something wrong with DNS settings, but when I ask my host, they say things are fine at their end. Does anyone have solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your blog host has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```
blog.mouryadandu.com.   3600    IN      CNAME   cpanel17.fozzy.com.
cpanel17.fozzy.com.     14400   IN      A       78.140.140.207
cpanel17.fozzy.com.     14400   IN      AAAA    2a00:1178:1:43:4::11
```

When accessing via the 78.140.140.207 address (IPv4), I see your blog just fine.  When accessing it via the 2a00:1178:1:43:4::11 address (IPv6), I get the cPanel redirect page (I assume this is the 404 people have been running into).

This is almost certainly a configuration error on the blog host.  Can you try enabling IPv6 via cPanel (https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Enable+IPv6)?